# Why am I getting a VBA Typer Mismatch Error?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Trying to create a conditional statement in my VBA code for a pivot table to highlight red any values less than 2 in Column C.

```
 Set result = Range("C:C").Value
             If result < 2 Then
                  MyRange.Font.ColorIndex = 3
             End If
```

Not sure why I'm getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: `Set` is used to save the Object in your variable. You're doing `Set var = .Value` so it is looking for an Object, but finding a Variant value instead. Remove `Set`

Comment: You can't compare an array to an integer. You also shouldn't be using `Set` with non-objects.

Comment: To check each cell's value, you'll want to do a loop through column C. You can't just do `result < 2`. You could also use conditional formatting, which would do the work for you and would also update automatically if the values change.

Comment: So what would be a better way to write this then?

Comment: conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I like the conditional formatting option.

otherwise something like this might work well:

```
Dim rng as range
for each rng in Range("C1:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).row)
    If rng.value < 2 Then
        rng.Font.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
next rng
```

*I haven't checked the actual application of colour*

this should get you a little closer